# pandas split and expand two columns

Tags: python, pandas

Split tag and author then expand to new rows.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
        {'name': 'book1', 'tag': 'a b c', 'author': 'a1 a2'},
    ],columns=['name', 'tag', 'author']);
print(df)

    name    tag author
0  book1  a b c  a1 a2
```

**Expected:**

```
[out]
    name tag author
0  book1   a     a1
1  book1   b     a2
2  book1   c    NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by all repeating values of columns, then reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True` for `DataFrame` and last reshape by `stack` with `unstack`:

```
df1 = (df.set_index('name')
         .stack()
         .str.split(expand=True)
         .stack()
         .unstack(1)
         .reset_index(level=0)
         .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df1)
    name tag author
0  book1   a     a1
1  book1   b     a2
2  book1   c    NaN
```

Another solution:

```
df1 = (df.set_index('name')
         .apply(lambda x: x.str.split(expand=True).stack())
         .reset_index(level=0)
         .reset_index(drop=True)
        )
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'

Answer (score 0):

For those with sufficiently updated Python to use the splat unpacking

```
from itertools import zip_longest
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(
    [n + m for *n, t, a in zip(*map(df.get, df))
           for *m,      in zip_longest(*map(str.split, (t, a)))],
    columns=[*df]
)

    name tag author
0  book1   a     a1
1  book1   b     a2
2  book1   c   None
```